# What should i do to get all the users with exactly two roles? as user 1 has 2 roles in database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

User.php

```
public function roles(){ return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class); }
```

Role.php

```
public function users(){ return $this->belongsToMany(User::class); }
```

UserController.php

```
$user = User::whereHas('roles', function ($q) use ($request) { $q->where('role_id', $request->roles); })
```

================Request========================

```
{ "roles":[1,2] }
```

===============Response=========================

```
[]
```

===============Table===============================
role_user

```
+===+===+
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 2 |
```

What should i do to get all the users with exactly two roles?
as user 1 has 2 roles in database

Comment: use `whereIn`  in your controller query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `whereIn` to only get users with the provided `role_ids`:

Role 1 **or** 2:

```php
$user = User::whereHas('roles', function ($q) use ($request) {
    $q->whereIn('role_id', $request->roles); // $request->roles needs to be an array
});
```

Role 1 **and** 2:

```php
$user = User::whereHas('roles', function ($q) use ($request) {
    $q->whereIn('role_id', $request->roles)
        ->groupBy('user_id')
        ->havingRaw('COUNT(DISTINCT role_id) = '.count($request->roles));
});
```

From the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries#where-clauses):

> The whereIn method verifies that a given column's value is contained
>   within the given array

```php
$users = DB::table('users')
    ->whereIn('id', [1, 2, 3])
    ->get();
```

Comment: it gives me all the users having role ('admin' or 'client'). i need only those user who have roles ('admin' and 'client') both...

Comment: @sahamnadeem I updated my answer, could you try again, it should now give you all users with the roles 1 and 2

Answer (score 0):

You can count the amount of roles in your query and then use the result as an attribute

```
$users = User::withCount('roles')->get()->where('roles_count',2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
Public function getRole()
$users=User::with('roles') - >first () ;
foreach ($users->roles as $user)
 {
$list[] =$user->name;
}
dd($list) ;
```